# How can I reuse an object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to reuse an object I created to dynamically create more than one slider on a page.
My idea was to create an array and push my slider object there as often as needed, so I could access it by id. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Hope someone can point me in the right direction ...

So what I have is this;

```
var slider = {
  "init":function(slide_it){
    this.parent = $(slide_it);
    /Count Elements and create a navigation depending on the count etc./
  },
  "otherstuff":{...}
}
```

In my (document).ready function I create an array and fill it up with different slider objects, add Ids to an accordion and call the init function:

```
var slide_array = [];
var accordion_sections = $('#accordion > div').length;
for(var i = 0; i < accordion_sections; i++){
  slide_array.push(slider);
  $('#accordion').children('div').eq(i).attr('id', 'slide_it_'+ i);
  slide_array[i].init($('#slide_it_' + i).find('.slider'));
}
```

Then I have a button with class="next" and I call a function within the slider

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  slide_array[0].otherstuff();
});
```

My plan is to get the parent of .next and its id so that I can use `slide_array[parentID].otherstuff();`

But ... it's not working propperly when I call the init function inside the for loop more then once.

More weird, some functions calls seem to work, other have no effect. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Object.create`.

```
var s1 = Object.create(slider),
    s2 = Object.create(slider);

s1.init(...);
s2.init(...);
```

If you return `this` from `init` your will be able to chain like:

```
var s1 = Object.create(slider).init(...);
```

However at this point I would just ditch the object literal and use constructors, since this is what you need.

```
function Slider(slide_it) {
    this.parent = $(slide_it);
}

Slider.prototype = {
    constructor: Slider,
    otherStuff: function () {}
};


var s1 = new Slider(...),
    s2 = new Slider(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to return the object:

```
function slider() {
  return {
    "init":function(slide_it){
      this.parent = $(slide_it);
      /Count Elements and create a navigation depending on the count etc./
    },
    "otherstuff":{...}
  };
}
```

Then:

```
slide_array.push( slider() );
```

That'll give you a separate object every time. In you're version, you're filling the array with references to the same single object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! I tried it and it seems to work, but I'm still getting some very strange behaviour. Need to analyse my code further ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just turn that into a [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) ?

```
jQuery.fn.slider = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var sliderElem = $(this),
            settings   = $.extend({
                speed : 3000,
                something : 'other thing'
            }, options);

        otherStuff(sliderElem);
    });

    function otherStuff(elem) {

    }
}

$('#accordion > div').slider();
```

No iteration or jumping through hoops, just call it on the collection and it creates a new slider for each element ?

Comment: Seems the more logical way to go

Comment: @A.Wolff - Thanks, wasn't at all sure if this was an option, I looked at that object and the loop at least ten times before posting, so glad someone agreed with me. This seems like exactly something that a jQuery plugin would be useful for ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've never build a jQuery plugin before. I will have a look at it and give it a try. I'm just overwhelmed how quick you guys answer. You're awesome!